# Return a key : value pair from a method for use in NSDictionary

Tags: objective-c, nsdictionary

I understand I can return an `NSDictionary` by doing

```
- (NSDictionary *)keyWithValue {
   return @{@"key" : @"value"};
}
```

but how can I return that without the enclosing `@{}` dictionary?

Comment: Are you asking "how can I return more than one value from a method"?

Comment: This question needs clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no tuples in Objective C unlike in Swift, Python etc. So the common way to return 2 different objects is to return an array or a dictionary.

You also can try something like:

```
- (NSString *)keyWithValue:(NSString**)value {
   *value = @"value";
   return @"key";
}
```

It should be used following way:

```
NSString *v;
NSString *k = [self keyWithValue:&v];
// now v contains @"value"
```

Comment: I keep hearing people suggest using either a dictionary or array because there is no tuple in Objective C. What's wrong with creating a tuple class yourself?

Comment: @TienDinh Will it be much better than immutable array (@[value1, value2, value3,...])?

Answer (score 0):

Objective-C, like C before it, doesn't allow the return of multiple values from a method. (Essentially, although a method or function can accept any number of arguments as input, it can only have a single return value.) There are historical and implementation reasons for this design but it can be frustrating when you simply have a pair/tuple to return.

If you have a method that has two distinct "results" that you need to return to the caller, you have a few choices. The very simplest in your case is to do something like what you are doing here and "wrapping" the values in a dictionary. You could similarly wrap them in a two-value array (which is a little less good since it relies on an implicit contract between caller and callee that there will be exactly two items in the array).

However, a clean and fairly standard approach here would be to create a small class with only two properties on it, and create, fill in, and return that instance with your pair of values. This arguably uses less runtime overhead than a collection object, and has the nice benefit of being semantically explicit and easy to understand for anyone else looking at it.

(There is yet another way, which involves passing pointers as arguments that are "outparams", but that's only idiomatic in rare circumstances in ObjC and I wouldn't recommend it here.)

Comment: Thanks.. I was trying to see if @"key" : @"value" was actually an object itself

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to return a key value pair without a dictionary because that is the definition of the dictionary data structure. From apple docs:

> The NSDictionary class declares the programmatic interface to objects that manage immutable associations of keys and values

You access the value with

```
[myDictionary objectForKey:@"myKey"];
```

If you want to use the returned key-value pair in another dictionary

```
NSMutableDictionary *otherDict = [NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[otherDict setObject:[myDictionary objectForKey:@"myKey"] forKey:@"myKey"];
```